# Quisiera Saber como capturar el id de un dropdown y que me lo muestre en la consola

Tags: reactjs

Hola que tal tengo un problema que me cuesta resolver, quiero capturar el id de un dropdown, quiero que al seleccionar una marca me aparezca el modelo de dicha marca.

https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-flower-00jnc4?file=/src/car.jsx

Comment: Hola Juan, el sandbox que colocaste no carga lo que quieres hacer. ¿Puedes colocar tu componente directamente y explicar qué es lo que has intentado?

Comment: al formular la pregunta, hay herramientas que te permiten adjuntar el codigo en formato texto, los enlaces despues de un tiempo dejan de ser utilizables y la pregunta pierde todo el sentido, lee [ask].